# How can I pre-select a value from a dropdown list with meteor and autoform?

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform

I'm using autoform with simple-schema and trying to pre-select a value from a dropdown list. I either crash the app or get no notice, no result, nothing. The selected value still shows (Select One). Here's the block from my schema:

```
status:{
  type: String,
  label: "Status",
  allowedValues: ['Approved','Pending','Flagged'],
  autoValue: function() {
    return {label: 'Pending', value: 'Pending'};
  }
},
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taken from the documentation: https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform#affieldinput

To specify a label to be displayed when there is no option selected, set **firstOption**="(My Select One Label)".

**firstOption:** Use with the options attribute to specify a string to use for the first option of a select input, which shows when nothing has been selected yet. For example, **firstOption**="(You Should Really Pick Something From This List)". There is a default first option "(Select One)". If you don't want any default option, then do firstOption=false, but make sure your select input has a default value or this will result in a confusing UX where it looks like the first option is selected but it isn't.

Answer (score 4):

Add the `value` attribute.

```
{{afQuickField name="fieldName" options="allowed" value="option1"}}
```

Found here: https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform/issues/52

Answer (score 1):

For me this worked:

```
status:{
  type: String,
  label: "Status",
  allowedValues: ['Approved','Pending','Flagged'],
  autoform: {
    afFieldInput: {
      firstOption: 'Pending'
   }
  }
},
```